# How do I get individual tree probabilities from Random Forests in R?

Tags: r, classification, prediction, random-forest

I'm using the randomForest package in R on a classification problem (outcome is binary). 
I want to get the probability output of each one of the trees (to get a prediction interval). 
I've set the predict.all=TRUE argument in the predictions, but it gives me a matrix of 800 columns (=the number of trees in my forest) and each of them is a 1 or a 0. How do I get the probability output rather than class?

PS: the size of my nodes=1, which means that this should make sense. however, I changed the node size=50, still got all 0's and 1's no probabilities.

Here's what Im doing:

```
#build model (node size=1) 
rf<-randomForest(y~. ,data=train, ntree=800,replace=TRUE, proximilty=TRUE, keep.inbag=TRUE)

#get the predictions 

#store the predictions from all the trees
all_tree_train<-predict(rf, test, type="prob", predict.all= TRUE)$individual
```

This gives a matrix of 0's and 1's rather than probabilities.

Answer (score 2):

I realise this question is old, but it might help anyone with a similar question.

If you query the trees for their results, you'll always get the end classifications which are deterministic given an initialised forest. You can extract the probabilities by setting predict all to TRUE as you've done and summing across the votes for a probability.

If you have more than 2 classes, the forest classifies an item 'm' as class 'x' with probability 
(number of trees which bin m as x)/(number of trees)

As you only have a binary classification, the column sums of the prediction matrix give you the probability of being in class 1.

Answer (score 1):

So the documentation for `predict.randomForest` states:

> If predict.all=TRUE, then the individual component of the returned
>   object is a character matrix where each column contains the predicted
>   class by a tree in the forest.

...so it does not appear that it is possible to have a probability returned for each individual tree.

If you want something like a prediction interval for classification, you might try fitting a random forest with many more trees and then generating predictions from many different (random?) subsets of the forest.

One thing you need to be careful of though is that you appear to be feeding your training data to `predict.randomForest`. This will of course give you biased predictions, unless you use the information from the `inbag` component of the random forest object to only select trees on which that observation was out of bag.

Comment: Ah, typo, I actually use the testing dataset. will edit. thanks